# Asymptotic at $\infty$ from Taylor series at $0$

Tags: complex-analysis, numerical-methods

Suppose I know a function which is analytic at zero, has no poles on the real axis, moreover I know that, for $x\to +\infty$

$$
f(x) = y_0 + e^{-\Delta x} + O\left ( e^{-2\Delta x} \right). 
$$

As I said I also know that
$$
f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k x^k
$$

and the series converges in a neighborhood of the origin. So we know all the coefficients $a_k$.

Is it possible to obtain the number $y_0$? What about $\Delta$? In principle by analytic continuation we can obtain the function along the entire real line.

*Edit*

As suggested in the comments one should also assume that the function is meromorphic. For my applications one can probably assume that the function is meromorphic on the entire complex plane. But one may assume even more if needed.

As a concrete example of the kind of function I am looking at, you can think of

\begin{align}
f(x) & = \tanh(x) \\
& = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{2^{2 k} \left(2^{2 k}-1\right) B_{2 k} }{(2 k)!} x^{2k-1}
\end{align}

where $B_{2k}$ are Bernoulli numbers. The series converges for $|x| < 4/\pi^2$ if I am not mistaken.

Of course knowing $f$ it is straightforward to obtain

$$
f(x) = 1-2x e^{-2x} + O(e^{-4x})
$$

for $x\to \infty$. Can I obtain the value $1$ from knowledge of the coefficient of the series above?

Comment: You are talking about meromorphic functions, aren't you?

Comment: Yes, you can also assume more if needed.

Comment: Maybe you should add this to your question for otherwise there is no single analytic continuation and the coefficients of the Taylor series are completelly independent of the behaviour of $f$ at $\infty$

Comment: I would be extremely surprised if there is a connection here. You're basically asking if you can a small $x$ representation of $f(x)$ to infer one of its large $x$ properties. The fundamental limitation of asymptotic formulas is that we *can't* use them to make inferences like this.

Comment: @kevinkayaks I understand your skepticism, but in principle the answer should be contained in the analytic continuation (isn't it?). And that only depends on the $a_k$.

Comment: @Icv you could have a look at R.P. Boas' 'Entire Functions'

Comment: @BrunoKrams Thanks for the suggestion. I'll take a look. (Even if my functions are not entire?)

Comment: @Icv Most likely you will not find an exact answer to your question there, but you might find something related